# Rotating text and pictures in 3D with javascript

Tags: javascript, text, 3d

I'm searching for a 3D javascript framework which allows to

- put 2D text (fonts, colors, bold, italic, etc)
- put 2D pictures
- rotate the text and the pictures in the 3D

I found some 3D engines for js but they don't support 2D text..

I would be very grateful if you can halp me. 
Marshal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) supports 3D rotation, and so does [TransformJS](http://transformjs.strobeapp.com/).

Also, have a look at [browser support for 3D transitions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d).

Comment: I haven't been accurate in my latest post. For a need not only 3D rotations but 3D translation. So for example I would like to do:
text.SetPosition(-30, -3, 4); 
text.SetRotation(0, 0, 1, 90);

Comment: @Marshall - edited my post, see [TransformJS](http://transformjs.strobeapp.com/) :)